# UWP Listview - Update textblock within DataTemplate at runtime

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to update a textblock within a DataTemplate used to load a listview at runtime. Each time the user clicks on the Increment or Decrement button, the lblRepeatNum has to be incremented or decremented accordingly.

I am having a hard time to access the textblock from inside the click event of the buttons. Please help.

XAML & c# code below.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvBuildYourRuqya" Grid.Row="1">

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <RelativePanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="lblVerseName" x:Name="lblVerseName" Height="35" Text="{Binding RuqyaName}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Padding="0,0,20,0" RelativePanel.RightOf="lblVerseName" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="lblRepeatNum" x:Name="lblRepeatNum" Text="{Binding NumOfTimes}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnIncrement" Width="35" Height="35" Tag="{Binding index}" Click="btnIncrement_Click" Content="+" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnDecrement" Width="35" Height="35" Tag="{Binding index}" Click="btnDecrement_Click" Content="-"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </RelativePanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>

private void btnDecrement_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //get index of selected row
        int index = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;

        //get object at this index
        Ruqya rq = (Ruqya) lvBuildYourRuqya.Items[index];

        //decrement 
        rq.NumOfTimes -= 1;

        //update lblRepeatNum
        ????????
    }
```

Comment: Does `NumOfTimes` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Try use binding

Answer (score 1):

As Justin XL said, you need to implement [`I​Notify​Property​Changed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) interface for the property you want to dynamic changed. So that once the `NumOfTimes` changed by code line `rq.NumOfTimes -= 1;` the `lblRepeatNum` will be changed automatically. For example, your `Ruqya` class could inherit the `I​Notify​Property​Changed` as follows:

```
public class Ruqya : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int _numOfTimes;
   public int NumOfTimes
   {
       get
       {
           return _numOfTimes;
       }

       set
       {
           this._numOfTimes = value;
           this.OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
   public string RuqyaName { get; set; }
   public int index { get; set; }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged =delegate { };

   public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
       // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
       this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

More details please reference [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).
For your scenario I also recommend you use  [`I​Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand) interface for the button click event handles, more details about this please reference [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-bind-command-to-a-299f7759).